# How to specify the date format to the function

Tags: linux, date

I understand that command `date -d "20170712"` validates and return the date in string form as `Wed Jul 12 00:00:00 PDT 2017`.

The questions I have are:

1. How does date know that format in which I gave the string (in this case Year as 2107, Month as Jul and Day as 12)?
2. Also what if I want to pass "20171307" and want to tell the function that day is 13th and month is Jul?
3. Is there a way to specify the format of the string I pass to `date` command?

Comment: Check out `info coreutils 'date invocation'` for detailed information about date program. There is section: "Date input formats"

Answer (score 3):

GNU `date` does its darndest to parse your input, but some formats are inherently ambiguous.

BSD `date` allows (or practically requires) you to specify an input format with `-f` and then simply parses your input according to that, throwing an error if the input doesn't match the format.

Expecting or requiring standard tools to support an illogical and haphazard date format like yours seems misdirected, anyway. Standard tools should support standard formats, and I think you'll find in the long run that it makes sense for your scripts and programs to use a computer-friendly fomat internally. For interfacing with humans with odd behaviors, it's easy enough to write a simple shell wrapper function like

```
Wackydate () {
    local day  # local is a Bashism
    local mon
    local year
    year=${1%????}
    mon=${1#$year??}
    day=${1#$year}
    day=${day%$mon}
    shift
    date -d "$year$mon$day" "$@"
}
```

The shell's parameter substitutions `${variable#prefix}` and `${variable%suffix}` return the value of `variable` with any wildcard match on the expression after `#` or `%` removed at the beginning or end, respectively.

Comment: It would be easier still if you restrict the script to Bash only, as there is a substring operator `${1:0:4}` but I wanted this to be portable to POSIX `sh` if you just drop the `local` declarations.

Comment: For those in linux: Please note that the open and quite small [busybox](https://busybox.net/about.html) has a date component that also allows the format of `-d` to be defined with `-D`.

Comment: I don't see how that affects people on Linux particularly, but thanks for the note.

Comment: Because of your line: **BSD** `date allows you to specify an input format `. If not in BSD, that is, in Linux: busybox date provide an equivalent solution.

Comment: Oh, I see.  There are many other environments like various legacy big-iron systems which have their own userland utilities so I don't think we can or want to build an exhaustive database of their `date` behaviors here; and installing Busybox just to get a custom date parser seems a bit excessive if you know the input date format anyway -- it should be just a few lines of shell or Awk or Perl script to massage it into something understood by GNU `date`.

Comment: It is you who started naming "userland utilities", but yes, a short awk, sed or even shell may solve some issues. As your answer shows.

Answer (score 2):

Please, oh Please, do not do this.

In general, the output of date is controlled by `LC_TIME` variable

```
$ LC_TIME=ja_JP.utf8 date; date'
2017年  7月 13日 木曜日 18:00:22 EDT
Thu Jul 13 18:00:22 EDT 2017
```

And it may be very (and I mean: really very) difficult to parse a date string even if it seems natural and obvious to the reader.

Like the Japan format above.

It could **not** be used back as input to the date command.

You can [edit the locale file](https://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/) to fit your needs and even make it the default.

> First, a quote:
>
> ```
>  Our units of temporal measurement, from seconds on up to months,
>  are so complicated, asymmetrical and disjunctive so as to make
>  coherent mental reckoning in time all but impossible.  Indeed, had
>  some tyrannical god contrived to enslave our minds to time, to make
>  it all but impossible for us to escape subjection to sodden
>  routines and unpleasant surprises, he could hardly have done better
>  than handing down our present system.  It is like a set of
>  trapezoidal building blocks, with no vertical or horizontal
>  surfaces, like a language in which the simplest thought demands
>  ornate constructions, useless particles and lengthy
>  circumlocutions.  Unlike the more successful patterns of language
>  and science, which enable us to face experience boldly or at least
>  level-headedly, our system of temporal calculation silently and
>  persistently encourages our terror of time.
>
>  ... It is as though architects had to measure length in feet, width
>  in meters and height in ells; as though basic instruction manuals
>  demanded a knowledge of five different languages.  It is no wonder
>  then that we often look into our own immediate past or future, last
>  Tuesday or a week from Sunday, with feelings of helpless confusion.
>  ...
> ```
>
> —Robert Grudin, ‘Time and the Art of Living’.

Answers:

1. Because it mostly conforms to the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format.
   Which could be printed as this:

   ```
   $ date -Id -d 20170713
   ```
2. Yes, you can use such an awkward format (with busybox date or BSD date):

   ```
   $ busybox date -D '%Y%d%m' -d "20171307"
   Thu Jul 13 00:00:00 EDT 2017
   ```

   And even print it in the same format:

   ```
   $ busybox date -D '%Y%d%m' -d "20171307" +'%Y%d%m'
   20171307
   ```
3. Yes, you can provide a format, and above in `2` is an example.

Comment: Nice quote. Almost reads the same with *"... It is as though architects had to measure length, width, and height in inches, feet, and yards."*

Comment: date -D command doesn't work.  Any suggestion?

Comment: @AlluSingh Have you installed [busybox](https://busybox.net/about.html) ? The normal linux `date` does **not** have a `-D` option.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it all depends on the version of `date` you are using.

GNU `date` expects the input date to be `yy[y]*mmdd` as in `20170713` (13th of July 2017) or `1000901123` (23rd November 100090, yes, the year is faaaar in the future ;-)). It prints dates reliably up until 10 dixits, not sure what it does for years beyond that ... year as `2140000000` works, year `2150000000` does not work on my system.

You can also use human expressions such as `date -d 'yesterday'`, again, not portable.

Use `sed` to reorganize your date to `yyyymmdd`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `yy[yy]mmdd`?

Comment: Yeah, sort of, because it accepts two digit years, but it accepts years up to a certain amount of digits ...

Comment: Seeing your updated question I think I withdraw my comment. That far into the future is plainly ridiculous ("we can do this even though it doesn't make sense..") !!